# List of Benign URLs

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a list of benign urls. I've seen that others have used the Yahoo URL Random Generator (random.yahoo.com/bin/ryl), but that link doesn't seem to work anymore. The other thing that I thought might work was seeding a crawler with the Alexa list.

Comment: what is a benign URL? a kind, generous URL?

Comment: I just meant not malicious. Not malware, phishing, etc.

Comment: If you can find a way to guarantee non-maliciousness, I think there's a patent or two waiting to be written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Common Crawl](http://commoncrawl.org/) data, which is loosely related to the Internet Archive and [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/)

> the Common Crawl Corpus encompasses over two petabytes of web crawl data collected over eight years and ongoing. As the largest, most comprehensive, open repository of web crawl data on the cloud, we contribute to the thriving open data commons that drives innovation, research, and education.

([wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Crawl))

- [Getting started](http://commoncrawl.org/the-data/get-started/)
- [Example projects](http://commoncrawl.org/the-data/examples/)

---

In particular, the URL index they use for the crawl

- https://github.com/trivio/common_crawl_index
- Direct download (218 GB, http://commoncrawl.org/2013/01/common-crawl-url-index/)

Comment: Can I assume that all of the urls are non-malicious?

Comment: To be sure, I'd ask them, and be clear about how you define "benign" (porn yes, phishing no)